# Android app inserting and displaying data in a ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm making an app where Epileptic users can store information into an SQLite database about seizures they have recently had and display view them in another activity via a ListView. The app stops working on the emulator when I press the submit data button and if I press any button or tab that brings me to the page (ActivityDiary) where they can view any records..

In the logcat I'm getting a critical RuntimeException .. here  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.administrator.seizuretrack, PID: 2783

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TimeTEXTDescriptionTEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE diary_table (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Date TEXT TimeTEXTDescriptionTEXT
```

Activity for submitting the data:

```
public class RecordSeizuresActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**instantiating the floating button objects**/
    FloatingActionButton homeBut;
    FloatingActionButton seizureBut;
    FloatingActionButton diaryBut;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;

    /**instantiate the objects for database handling**/
    private Button butAddData, butViewData;
    private EditText dateText, timeText, desText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rec_seizures);

        /************Database code in onCreate method*************************/
        /**Create an instance of Database Helper class, call the constructor**/
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        timeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        desText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desText);
        butAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butAddData);
        butViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butViewData);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        butAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getDate = dateText.getText().toString();
                String getTime = timeText.getText().toString();
                String getDescription = desText.getText().toString();

                if (dateText.length() != 0 && timeText.length() != 0 && desText.length() != 0){

                    AddData(getDate, getTime, getDescription);
                    /**reset the text boxes so that they are blank**/
                    dateText.setText(" ");
                    timeText.setText(" ");
                    desText.setText(" ");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

            butViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordSeizuresActivity.this,ActivityDiary.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void AddData(String getDate, String getTime, String getDescription){
        boolean insertData = myDB.AddData(getDate, getTime, getDescription);

        if (insertData == true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Entered A New Seizure Record!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

DatabaseHelper: 
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SeizureTrack.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "diary_table";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Date";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Time";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Description";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COL_2 + " TEXT " + COL_3 + "TEXT" + COL_4 + "TEXT");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean AddData(String item, String item2, String item3) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, item);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, item2);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, item3);

        Log.d(TAG, "AddData: Adding " + item + item2 + item3 + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        /**if data is inserted incorrectly it will return -1**/
        if (result == -1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}

activity for viewing the data: 

public class ActivityDiary extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton homeBut;
    FloatingActionButton seizureBut;
    FloatingActionButton diaryBut;

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<User> userList;
    ListView listView;
    User user;

    /**instantiate the objects for database handling**/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Diary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        homeBut = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingHomeButton);
        homeBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityDiary.this, HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });
        seizureBut = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingRecSeizuresButton);
        seizureBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityDiary.this, RecordSeizuresActivity.class));
            }
        });
        diaryBut = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingDiaryButton);
        diaryBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityDiary.this, ActivityDiary.class));
            }
        });

        /************Database code in onCreate method*************************/
        /**Create an instance of Database Helper class, call the constructor**/
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();

        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if(numRows == 0){
            /**handles all NullPointerExceptions**/
            Toast.makeText(ActivityDiary.this, "You No Have Seizures On Record!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                user = new User(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3));
                userList.add(user);
            }

            ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, userList);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}

List adapter class: 

public class ThreeColumn_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private LayoutInflater uInflater;
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    private int uViewResourceId;


    public ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> users){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
        uInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        uViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parents){
        User user = users.get(position);

        if(user != null){
            TextView getDes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeizureType);
            TextView getDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            TextView getTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTime);

            if(getDes != null){
                getDes.setText((user.getDescription()));
            }
            if(getDate != null){
                getDate.setText((user.getDate()));
            }
            if(getTime != null){
                getTime.setText((user.getTime()));
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

Manifest file: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.seizuretrack">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login1"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.administrator.seizuretrack.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".RecordSeizuresActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivitySettings"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityDiary"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you forgot some commas in your create query

Answer (score 1):

**update your** `db.execSQL` **query** like this

```
 String CREATE_BILL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME +
            "("
            + id +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COL_2 +
            " TEXT,"
            + COL_3 +
            " TEXT,"
            + COL_4 + " TEXT" + ")";      


    db.execSQL(CREATE_BILL_TABLE);
```

Comment: @DonalLane; Upgrade your database version or uninstall your app from the device and run the app again

Comment: @NileshRathod; It would be nice if you edit your answer so it includes the steps required to let the application rerun this SQL statement

Comment: i just forgot my friend busy in some work thank you so much for your comments

Comment: Thanks that worked, I changed id to COL_1 and it displayed the toast saying the insert was a success.. However I can still cannot view the data in the next activity the app stops when I press the view button

Comment: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space. this is the reason, I think it is something to do with inserts I have done before and no space in the Layout or ListView to display them? I am correct in saying this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback the insertions are working for me now at least

Answer (score 0):

It's better to consider using some ORM instead of using SQLite directly.
There are some variants:

1) Realm: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started

2) GreenDao: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/updating-to-greendao-3-and-annotations/

3) etc...